# Improper integral $\int_0^\infty x\sin(x^3) dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

I need to check if the following integral converges / diverges conditionally.  $$\int_0^\infty x\sin(x^3) dx$$

I have tried integrating by parts and it didn't work.
Will appreciate any help :).

Comment: Tried that as well. Didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: @ShaharZiv It would be better if you'd write all that you tried in your question

Comment: Just a question I am not familiar with convergence and divergence however is it necessary to compute the integral itself to check for those? The integral in itself seems to have no simple solution and the answer uses functions such as Li

Comment: there are several convergene test for improper integral suvh as Abel's or Dirichlet's test which do not involve directly calculating the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The convergence can be based on the alternating series test.

Let $0 < \alpha < \beta$. Then

$$
\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} x \sin(x^3) \, dx 
= \int_{\alpha^3}^{\beta^3} t^{1/3} \sin(t) \cdot \frac13 t^{-2/3} \, dt
= \frac13 \int_{\alpha^3}^{\beta^3} t^{-1/3} \sin(t)\, dt
$$ by change of variables, so your integral converges if and only if
$$
\int_{2\pi}^{\infty} t^{-1/3} \sin(t)\, dt 
$$
converges; it does since the subsequent integrals

$$
\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi} t^{-1/3} \sin(t)\, dt, \int_{3\pi}^{4\pi} t^{-1/3} \sin(t)\, dt, \cdots
$$
form an alternating sequence which decreases monotonically in absolute value and converges to zero.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so applying Yves' suggestion I get:
$\int_0^\infty x\sin(x^3) dx = \int_0^\infty\sin(t)/t^{-3}dt$ which converges. Thank you!

Comment: I think you might be missing a factor of $3$ somewhere. Also, to make this more useful for future readers, you could add some more information as to why the second integral converges! :)

Comment: Sorry, your change of variable is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: You can start from

$$\sin x=\frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}}{2i}$$
hence your integral can be written like:

$$\int_0^\infty x\sin(x^3) dx=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{ix\left(\mathrm{e}^{ix^3}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix^3}\right)}{2i^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty-\dfrac{ix\left(\mathrm{e}^{ix^3}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix^3}\right)}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$=\frac i2\int_0^\infty x\left(\mathrm{e}^{ix^3}-\mathrm{e}^{-ix^3}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Last integral is simple to solve using the substitution $t=-x^2 \iff \mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2x}\,\mathrm{d}t$ for $\int_0^\infty x\mathrm{e}^{ix^3}\,\mathrm{d}x$.

It is necessary to remember incomplete gamma function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function