Rieman integrable function on [0,$\infty$)
In one of the tasks from S. Resnick's "Adventures of Stochastic Processes" the author asks to construct a Riemann integrable function on $[0,\infty)$, which is unbounded and continuous.
By definition, $f$ is R-integrable on $[0,a]$ for all $a>0$ if $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx = \lim_{a\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^af(x)dx$. Moreover, for a function to be Riemann integrable on $[0,\infty)$, it does not have to be bounded.
One of the possible solutions is presented here, i.e. $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      0 & x= 0 \\
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & 0< x\leqslant1 \\
      \frac{1}{x^2} & x > 1 
   \end{cases}
$$
The problem with this answer is that there is a breaking point at $x=0$. In other words, this function is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ and not on $[0,\infty)$.
I was thinking about $x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which is also continuous and unbounded on the interval and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$ (since even though $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ oscillates between $1$ and $−1$ as $x$ approaches $0$ the limit still exists)?
The issue I face is with the function's behavior around $x=0$. Perhaps someone could provide some guidance on what I should look for?

Your example of $x^2\sin(1/x)$ does not have a finite integral (since it grows to infinity for large $x$). To get a continuous function, it must be bounded at 0, so instead we need would need unbounded oscillations to happen at infinity. I think something like $x\sin(x^3)$ might work, but I haven't gone through the details. However, it would certainly be more natural to require $f$ to only be continuous in $(0,\infty)$...

&Milten your suggestion appears to work see the first answer to  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750757/improper-integral-int-0-infty-x-sinx3-dx
